# Buckling on beam in solidworks

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

[image]

[image]

Dear all, what does AMPRES stands for in solidworks buckling? It seems like it does not have any unit. I am actually trying to find what is the **max resultant stress** on this beam and I am not sure how these AMPRES data I got help to find the max stress? The force I applied to the top of the beam to buckle it is 10,000 N .

Thank you for reading and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I believe AMPRES is "resultant amplitude". I would think it has arbitrary units for linear buckling analysis. To calculate max stress in the beam you can perform static analysis. AMPRES would not help you. There is no buckling at your load (the critical buckling load is 86 times greater).